# How to understand "as compatible" in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> But the play's complex view of Black self-esteem and human solidarity ***as compatible*** is no more "contradictory" than Du Bois' famous, well-considered ideal of ethnic self-awareness coexisting with human unity, or Fanon's emphasis on an ideal internationalism that also accommodates national identities and roles.

I don't understand "as compatible" in the sentence. It looks out of place to me. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**compatible**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/compatible) means able to exist or occur together without problems or conflict.

If my view is that something is useful, it means I *consider* it or *deem* it useful. To view two things as compatible means to consider them or deem them compatible: to consider them able to co-exist without problems or conflict.

Apparently the play **views** Black self-esteem **as** compatible with human solidarity: it says they can co-exist without problems or conflict.

It sees three pairs of things as compatible:

Black self-esteem is compatible with human solidarity, just as ethnic self-awareness is compatible with human unity, and an ideal nationalism is compatible with national identities and roles.

Word hippo has many synonyms for [view as](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/view_as.html).

Answer (score 1):

I mean the sentence says that [Black self-esteem and human solidarity] are presented [as (if/though they are)]/[to be]/[like things that are] compatible (with each other).

Like the author expects a contradiction between [black self-esteem] and [human solidarity] and so emphasizes that the play views them as compatible with each other and goes on to give examples how that idea is not new but already explored elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

We can use 'as' to say what someone thinks or says a thing or things are.

The play's view (opinion) of Black self-esteem and human solidarity is that they are compatible.

The traveller viewed lions and tigers as dangerous. (The traveller believed that they are dangerous)

I view free bus travel as a good thing. (I believe that it is a good thing)

> As
>
> preposition, adverb
>
> 3 used to say what someone thinks or says a person or thing is
>
> *The problem is regarded as serious.*
> *The result of last week’s election will be seen as a victory for the
> right-wing government*.
> *He’s described as being in his late teens,
> tall, and of slim build.*

[As (Longman Dictionary)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/as)